# Javascript inheritence of child object on prototype

Tags: javascript, inheritance

I am just starting to learn prototype inheritance in JS and I would like the child object (**def2**) of my subclass object to inherit from superclass object's child object (**def**). The following code will explain what I mean:

```
function Animal(name)
{
    this.name = name;       
    this.def = {
        FieldA: 'aaa',
        FieldB: 'bbb'
    }
}

function Rabbit(name, category)
{
    Animal.apply(this, arguments);  

    this.def2 = { };        
    this.def2.prototype = Animal.def;       
    alert(this.def2.FieldA);  // this is undefined 

}
```

Comment: you would have to say  this.def2 = new Animal(name). if you use prototype, you use "new ".

Comment: I dont want def2 to have properties/methods from Animal, but from Animal.def

Comment: what you describe: this.def2 = this.def;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function Rabbit(name, category) {
    Animal.apply(this, arguments);
    this.def2 = clone(this.def); //where clone is a function similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/most-efficient-way-to-clone-an-object#answer-122190   

    alert(this.def.FieldA);  // this is 'aaa'
}
Rabbit.prototype = new Animal(); //inherit Animal
Rabbit.prototype.constructor = Rabbit;
```

I suggest you read http://phrogz.net/JS/classes/OOPinJS2.html or a similar article

Comment: Ok, but now in rabbit i want to define another object called def2, which should inherit properties of Animal.def. How do I do this?

Comment: is Animal.def always going to be an object say defaults?

Comment: Then clone it - not sure why you want to clone it though. I'll update my code

Comment: with $.extend() right? I was thinking about cloning, but for some reason didnt go that path

Comment: Yes, `jQuery.clone(this.def)` or `jQuery.extend({}, this.def)` is what you're looking for I believe